# Apache for http + https: Unwanted redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, https, apache2

I want a site to be served both for http and https. With the configuration as pasted below, apache starts without any error or warning. the site is a wordpress installation. Now, accessing the server on https works fine. However, accessing port 80 gets a redirect - which I don't want because it breaks my routing. Here is what access log shows: `36.9.152.171 - - [05/Feb/2015:08:16:05 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 586 "-" "curl/7.30.0"` - this happens when I do a `curl http://acme.com`. Where could this 302 come from? Could it be wordpress? How can I get rid of it?

**default site**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName acme.com
    SSLEngine off
    ServerAdmin info@acme.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acme  
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/acme>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**default-ssl site**
    
        ServerName acme.com
        ServerAdmin info@acme.com

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acme
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/acme>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**ports.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**apache.conf**

```
 ### Section 1: Global Environment
 #
 # The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
 # such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
 # can find its configuration files.
 #

 #
 # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
 # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
 #
 # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
 # mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
 # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
 # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
 #
 # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
 #
 #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

 #
 # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
 #
 LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

 #
 # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
 # identification number when it starts.
 # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
 #
 PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

 #
 # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
 #
 Timeout 300

 #
 # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
 # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
 #
 KeepAlive On

 #
 # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
 # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
 # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
 #
 MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

 #
 # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
 # same client on the same connection.
 #
 KeepAliveTimeout 5

 ##
 ## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
 ## 

 # prefork MPM
 # StartServers: number of server processes to start
 # MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
 # MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
 # MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
 # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
 <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
     StartServers          5
     MinSpareServers       5
     MaxSpareServers      10
     MaxClients          150
     MaxRequestsPerChild   0
 </IfModule>

 # worker MPM
 # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
 # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
 # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
 # ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
 #              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
 #              and starting Apache.
 # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
 # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
 # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
 <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
     StartServers          2
     MinSpareThreads      25
     MaxSpareThreads      75 
     ThreadLimit          64
     ThreadsPerChild      25
     MaxClients          150
     MaxRequestsPerChild   0
 </IfModule>

 # event MPM
 # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
 # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
 # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
 # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
 # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
 # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
 <IfModule mpm_event_module>
     StartServers          2
     MinSpareThreads      25
     MaxSpareThreads      75 
     ThreadLimit          64
     ThreadsPerChild      25
     MaxClients          150
     MaxRequestsPerChild   0
 </IfModule>

 # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
 User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
 Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

 #
 # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
 # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
 # directive.
 #

 AccessFileName .htaccess

 #
 # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
 # viewed by Web clients. 
 #
 <Files ~ "^\.ht">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
     Satisfy all
 </Files>

 #
 # DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
 # if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
 # If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
 # a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
 # or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
 # keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
 # text.
 #
 # It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
 # client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
 # browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
 # where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
 # unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
 # incorrect  metadata.
 #
 DefaultType None


 #
 # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
 # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
 # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
 # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
 # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
 # nameserver.
 #
 HostnameLookups Off

 # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
 # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
 # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
 # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
 # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
 #
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

 #
 # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 #
 LogLevel warn

 # Include module configuration:
 Include mods-enabled/*.load
 Include mods-enabled/*.conf

 # Include all the user configurations:
 Include httpd.conf

 # Include ports listing
 Include ports.conf

 #
 # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
 # a CustomLog directive (see below).
 # If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
 #
 LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
 LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
 LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

 # Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
 # see README.Debian for details.

 # Include generic snippets of statements
 Include conf.d/

 # Include the virtual host configurations:
 Include sites-enabled/
```

**httpd.conf** (empty)

**/var/www/acme/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

(there's nothing else in my .htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like the 302 has indeed come from wordpress. I had it changed through the web interface to use `https://acme.com` as the site URL because there were some errors with resources not being loaded when trying to access the site through https and the site URL still being set to http in WP. Once forcing it back to http by adding `define('WP_HOME','http://web.protogrid.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://web.protogrid.com');` to `wp-config.php`, it worked again.

I just hate how WP rewrites URLs - why even do that in the CMS at all? I'd expect a good CMS to only use relative URLs so I can move it without doing a data migrations. Oh well...

My takeaway on this: WP only works with https if you *only* use https. In order to implement this I first had to move it out of my dynamic reverse proxy (hipache) and use static routes again.